# Python image search wrapper

Tags: python, search, data-mining

I'm trying to figure out a straightforward way to do some image searching in Python with larger numbers of return results than Google's API allows, i.e. 64.  I spent some time trying to use the Python [Boss Mashup Framework](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/mashup.html), and I followed the install instructions carefully, but attempting to do any searches always returns authorization errors.

I basically just want to search on a term and grab the first, say, 100 image urls that come up.  The particular search engine doesn't matter.  Any advice on a simple way to do this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is simple enough, but you could use [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to directly access Google Image search, click the next link for more results, etc. It's very easy to use, almost trivial.